# transfer a session between an admin and a user simultaneously spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session

I am trying to create a mini chat application that has users table. The users table has a field called isAdmin that identifies that such a particular user is an admin and if isAdmin is set to false such a user is a customer

**the user.java table fields**

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long timestamp;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private boolean isAdmin;
```

When I am trying to save a user, I try maintaining a request-response setAttribute method parameter using email field to hold the session attribute email is unique in my db

**snippet of the code**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/create-user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView createUser(HttpServletRequest request,
                                   HttpServletResponse response,
                                   @RequestParam String name,
                                   @RequestParam String email) {
        try {
            // create new user object
            User user = new User();
            user.setName(name);
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setTimestamp(new Date().getTime());

            // save user in db (if new)
            if (_userDao.getByEmail(email) == null) {
                request.getSession().setAttribute("email", email);
                _userDao.save(user);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            //logger.error("Exception in creating user: ", e.getStackTrace());
        }

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }
```

I am getting all the chats by email using requests.getSession.getAttribute as shown

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/get-all-chats", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Chat> getAllChats(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        String email = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("email");
        try {
            if (email != null) {

                return _chatDao.getAll(email);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Exception in fetching chats: ", e.getStackTrace());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

my dao method has a query to retrieve all the chats based on the email session attribute that was set

```
public List getAll(String email) {
        String hql = "from Chat c where c.user.email = :email";
      return  _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql).setParameter("email", email).list();
```

my challenge/confusion is that when I fetch the chat the user can only see his chat and the admin can only see his chat. the chat is not transferred between the admin and the user. Kindly assist.

Comment: Can you show the code where you're actually populating the `Chat` table?  Based on what you've provided thus far however, I would presume that since you're querying based on a chat's user email reference, it would just fetch chats for that user.

Comment: that is the getAll(args) method is what populates from the chat table

Comment: How can a `select` statement populate a table?